# Can I get WinEdT 9.0 or 10.1 to spell check the source file in Portuguese?

Tags: winedt, spelling

I am cutting and pasting Portuguese text into a LaTeX file (to translate an article that has a lot of math and graphics).  It is working fine.  I use:

```
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

But the source file is being spellchecked in English as I go, working in WinEdt 9.0.

I can live with that if there is no easy alternative.  But is there an easy way to get WinEdt 9.0 to spellcheck the source file in Brazilian Portuguese?

Comment: http://www.winedt.org/dict.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can go to [WinEdt.org](http://www.winedt.org/dict.html) dictionaries page and download one of the three Portuguese unicode dictionaries (there is a Brazilian one). I advise to use the `Installdict.edt` macro for the installation.

To have it fully efficient I suggest you define a `Portuguese` submode and enable the Brazilian dictionary for documents which have this submode. This way, if you work with English as well as Portuguese documents, the relevant dictionary will be loaded for each document. The submodes defined by default are `DE`, `FR`, `UK` and `US`.